# How to use "aws s3 cp" to output a directory or wildcard to stdout

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have been able to use to --recursive successfully for multiple files and the "-" destination for stdout but can not seem to use them together.  For example:

This works:

aws s3 cp s3://mybucket-ed/test/ . --recursive

```
download: s3://mybucket-ed/test/upload-0 to ./upload-0

download: s3://mybucket-ed/test/tower.json to ./tower.json
```

And this works:

aws s3 cp s3://mybucket-ed/test/upload-0 -

```
...

upload-0 file contents

...
```

But this returns nothing:

```
aws s3 cp s3://mybucket-ed/test/ - --recursive
```

Any suggestions short of listing out the directory contents and doing individual cp commands for each file?  Note that I just need all of the files in the S3 directory sent out to stdout (and not necessarily the recursive option).

Comment: Try writing a bug ticket in the GitHub project

Comment: @user4678808 What do you expect to get on stdout, when you try recursively fetch bunch of files? Do you expect them to be concatenated? Or comming in form of tar file?
I think, that fetching multiple files into stdout is very unclear scenario and shall be avoided.

Comment: Yes, they would be concatenated.  I don't see it being any different than if I were to "cat" multiple local files.